# How can I calculate NewTime in Spotfire

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns, spotfire

I want to make a new calculated column where DateTime of  "Class(Working) & Value(TRUE)" = DateTime of  "Class(not Working) & Value(not TRUE)"

and when it find new DateTime of "Class(Working) & Value(TRUE)" it should have the new value for the DateTime

Check my figure.

I Really Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You're going to need and `over` clause. What's the order of this data? how is it sorted?

Comment: I tried it.
but it didn't work well.

sort by DateTime and Equipment.